# Как правильно прочитать файл с текстом?

Tags: java, android

У меня есть файл в котором 3 строчки, я его прочитываю складываю в стринг билдер и потом билдер устанавливаю в вью для показа, вроде как все стандартно.

Вопрос в том, что будет если файл будет на 3 строчки а 100 страниц, насколько правильно читать данные в таком обьме в билдер и хватит ли ему памяти?

Comment: а асинктаском хватит

Comment: @АндроидАндроид я предполагаю, что проблема может быть в том, что сам стринг билдер получиться очень большого размера... или это исключено? Просто чтоб не получилось так, что сейчас файл маленький и все работает, потом будет тяжелый файл и все упадет...

Comment: Если посмотреть исходники StringBuilder, то будет понятно, что он в себе хранит char[]. Соответственно ответ на вопрос про память я думаю очевиден

Comment: @AndrewBystrov Наверное я еще не успел понять суть програмирования, но мне не очевидно)) Что это означает?

Comment: У массива есть переменная length - количество элементов. Эта переменная типа int => максимальное количество элементов в массиве - 2147483647. Размер char - 2 байта. => 2*2147483647 ~ 4 GB. Я, конечно, могу ошибаться

Comment: Простой код, который в цикле добавляет в стрингбилдер символ 'a' упал на 1207959550 итерации, т.е. примерно этот билдер "весит" около 1.1 GB. Но, в принципе, 1гб на массив я думаю Вам достаточно будет

Comment: @AndrewBystov если я правильно понял,  то файлы +/- до 4 гб легко может обрабатывать стринг билдер?

Comment: Ок понял........